# Deleting Events with Tombstones and Public / Private Data in an Event-Sourced System

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

David Schmitz mentions a solution for deleting user data in an event-sourced system [in this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzrZworHpIk&feature=youtu.be&t=2113). It works like this:

- Delete all events of the user
- Emit a Tombstone Event for this specific user
- Other services might listen to the Tombstone event and clean up data, too

#### **Question #1**

**To which stream is the tombstone event written?**

The event stream of the specific user? Or is there an event stream specifically for tombstone events?

---

Furthermore, to keep some data (e.g. the users' id), he advises to split the user stream into a public and private event stream. ([Reference to the talk](https://youtu.be/GzrZworHpIk?t=2205))

#### **Question #2**

**How would you practically append events to both streams?**

Let's say a command needs to append an event to both, the public and private user stream. How can you make sure that both events have been appended? Does the event store publish both, `SomeUserEventHapppendPrivate` and `SomeUsererEventHappendPublic`, to the event bus? Would you create snapshots for both stream independently? This seems to me like a lot of overhead.

---

P.S. I would like the hear about other strategies (besides encrypting events and then deleting the key) to deleting data in an event-sourced system, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:** You can start with one event, UserDeleteRequested which has two flags, one for public and one for private. You would have a BoundedContext (and associated stream) responsible for this change. Other services can listen to that event as you described.

**Question 2:** As for separating the the data into two streams, that sounds like two Aggregates within the same BC. How would you practically append events to both streams? You would use a process/saga to load each aggregate and raise tombstone events in what is effectively a two phase commit.

Comment: Question #1: Could further explain what you mean by "flags"? And as I understood you correctly, the `UserDeleteRequested` event will be stored in the stream of the user that is deleted?

Comment: Question #2: So I would append e.g. a `SomeUserEventHapppendPrivate` to the private stream and use a saga to trigger `SomeUsererEventHappendPublic` to be appended to the public stream? And the event store would publish both events the the event bus?

Comment: @flolu Question #1: By flags, I simply meant boolean values. You can raise an event, UserDeleteRequested(public = true, private = false). And yes, this event would be in the stream of the UserAggregate.

Comment: @flolu Question #2: I was referring specifically to the question of adding a tombstone event to both of the streams, public and private. You would raise the UserDeleteRequested event in the User stream and then using a saga, propagate those changes to the public and private Aggregate/streams. 

Much of this depends on your implementation and definitions of streams and aggregates so take all of this with a grain of salt.